# Why not use static_cast instead of dynamic_cast if I already checked the typeid?

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast, static-cast

The code below checks if the object from the `p` pointer is from the type `Student`, and if this is the case does a **dynamic_cast**.

**But why can't we do a static_cast ?**

I assume the casting is safe because we checked if the object from the pointer is from the correct Type, and a **static_cast** is faster.

```
void testRTTI (Persoon ∗p){
if (strstr (type id (∗p).name(), "Student")!=NULL){
Student ∗ s = dynamic_cast<Student ∗>(p) ;
s−>studeer();
}
else p−>doe();
}
```

Comment: That's not really how `typeid` is supposed to work or be used. The `name` function isn't even guaranteed to return a string with the actual class name.

Comment: And if you have a selection like this depending on class in an inheritance hierarchy, then that's a sign you should really use a single `virtual` function (which you give a *good* name).

Comment: if (typeid(*p) == typeid(Student))' Is this a cleaner way?

Comment: What is the reason that you don’t do the `dynamic_cast` directly and check if the result is `nullptr` or not. Why do you expect that `type_id` should be faster then `dynamic_cast` alone?

Comment: The typeid would be faster because it avoids doing a dynamic_cast if the cast is not appropriate, which I was taught to be slow.

Comment: I think the "because it doesn't work" reason is sufficient to not use `static_cast` here.

Answer (score 3):

You can just remove the `typeid` check, and only check if `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr` or not:

```
void testRTTI (Persoon *p){
  if (Student * s = dynamic_cast<Student *>(p); s != nullptr){
    s->studeer();
  } else {
    p->doe();
  }
}
```

I think you have a misunderstanding of what dynamic casting a pointer will do. For `dynamic_cast<T*>` it will first check if the pointer passed to `dynamic_cast<T*>` can be cast in a valid way to `T*`. This test is not more expensive than your `typeid(*p).name()` (at least not for the given case), and most certainly less expensive then `strstr(typeid(*p).name(), "Student")!=NULL`.

If it can't be cast to `T*` it will return `nullptr` if it can be cast it will return the same pointer cast to `T*` which does not need to be an operation at all.

So your code does two checks, one with your `typeid` and one in `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Just note that the `if(<init>;<condition>)` syntax you use only works in C++17 and later. For earlier versions, you have to separate out the variable declaration, but you can still initialize and check it inside the `if`, eg `Student *s; if ((s = dynamic_cast<Student*>(p)) != nullptr)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strstr(typeid (∗p).name(), "Student")!=NULL)
```

is flawed in two ways.

1. The function [`name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) returns an implementation defined value with no garantues whatsoever. The value might change from one run to another and it might be a random string.
2. ignoring the first problem: What if you have another class where `typeid(...).name()` would return a string that also contains `"Student"`?

---

That's why you have `dynamic_cast`:

```
Student ∗ maybeAStudent = dynamic_cast<Student ∗>(p);

if(maybeAStudent != nullptr)
{ /* p is a Student, do student things*/ }
else 
{ /* p is another Person, do person things */}
```

---

Note: `dynamic_cast` works only if `Person` has at least one virtual function.

Comment: And if I used the:  if (typeid(*p) == typeid(Student))?

Comment: @Desperate Should work, but it probably won't complie without `dynamic_cast`, I'm not 100% sure. But `dynamic_cast` is made for this and should be used. And we have a nice [formatting-help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) here :)

Comment: A further problem: anything involving `typeid(*p)` will fail if `Student` is subclassed